# Why Brightcove videos are not playing in IE 11? but it woking in IE11 in-private browsing mode

Tags: sitecore, brightcove

Why Brightcove videos are not playing in IE 11? but it woking  in IE11 in-private browsing mode
System Info:
Windows 10 
Integrating with sitecore CMS using jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Also: what video format? Do these exact same videos play when they're served by a plain vanilla HTTP server?

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide, it will be easier to replicate and provide solution. Also does it work in all the browsers. 
Also I would suggest that try to troubleshoot. You can take help from https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/troubleshooting-why-a-video-wont-play